# python re only splits on first of several variable-length delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I want to use re to split a string based on multiple, variable-length delimiters.

I tried:

```
s = 'PPPPMMMMMPPPPPFFFMFFFFAA--AAA'
re.split('(P*)|(A*)|(-*)', s)
```

and got:

```
['', 'PPPP', None, 'MMMMM', 'PPPPP', None, 'FFFMFFFFAA--AAA']
```

However, I'd like to fully split on all groups, like this:

```
['', 'PPPP', None, 'MMMMM', 'PPPPP', None, 'FFFMFFFF', 'AA', '--', 'AAA']
```

I don't mind the `None` entries.  I want a full split on all character blocks, including `P*`, `A*`, and `-*`.  Is this possible with `re`?

Comment: You cannot split on `x*`, it should be `x+`. Python gives a warning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the program with your given regex, you  get:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py:203: FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
  return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
```

This thus means that your regex should always contain at least one character: the *empty string* should not match the regex.

What about splitting on `(P+|A+|-+)`:

```
>>> re.split('(P+|A+|-+)', s)
['', 'PPPP', 'MMMMM', 'PPPPP', 'FFFMFFFF', 'AA', '', '--', '', 'AAA', '']
```

If you do not want the empty strings `''` you can filter them out with *list comprehension*:

```
>>> [x for x in re.split('(P+|A+|-+)', s) if x]
['PPPP', 'MMMMM', 'PPPPP', 'FFFMFFFF', 'AA', '--', 'AAA']
```

This also removes the `None` entries. If you however want the `None` parts (these are capture groups of the branches not taken), you can use `(P+)|(A+)|(-+)`:

```
>>> re.split('(P+)|(A+)|(-+)', s)
['', 'PPPP', None, None, 'MMMMM', 'PPPPP', None, None, 'FFFMFFFF', None, 'AA', None, '', None, None, '--', '', None, 'AAA', None, '']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.split('(P+)|(A+)|(-+)', s)
['', 'PPPP', None, None, 'MMMMM', 'PPPPP', None, None, 'FFFMFFFF', None, 'AA', None, '', None, None, '--', '', None, 'AAA', None, '']
```